# Unable to insert data to mongoDB through my nodejs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have my mongo DB set up and running in the google cloud server. 
I have my nodejs code in the server which tries to connect to the database and insert data into a collection. But this doesn’t seem to be working. The data does not get inserted.
It does not throw any specific error message.
When I manually create a database in mongoShell and insert data into a collection, the data gets inserted.
I also have my code connecting to mongo DB locally in my system and inserting data which still works fine.

What do you think could be a problem here?
Below is the code snippet for connecting to mongo DB and inserting data.

```
function insertDataInMongo(a) {

    var deferred = q.defer();

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/MyMongoDB’;
    var token = a[1];
    MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
        if(err) deferred.reject(new Error(err))
        console.log("connected for insert");


        var apiData = JSON.parse(a[0]);

        if(apiData.data){


            db.collection(‘TestCollection1’).update(apiData.data, {upsert:true});
            console.log(“Data inserted in TestCollection1“);
        }

        else {

            db.collection(‘TestCollection2’).update(apiData, {upsert:true});
            console.log(“TestCollection2”);
        }

        deferred.resolve(token);

    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: `db.collection('...').update()` also returns a promise. Did you try to wait for that promise? In your code you just proceed without waiting

Comment: No, I didn't wait for that promise, it just worked locally on my system, so I expected the same. Even if the promise didn't return in time, the db should be created ... 

as I was typing this, I noticed that I am using update, but for when there is no collection / db, I think I should use insert, and update only after the collection exists. Going to try that.

Comment: Ok.. the issue was that I was using update instead of insert. For update to work, it needs to have atleast the collection created once, and then the upsert / update will take care of it.

Wonder if there is a command that will create the collection and insert / update in one go, instead of having to do insert in the first pass and then switch to update there after, to avoid inserting duplicates.